# Help with c# threading

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a new thread and within the background thread method I do work and then call another method to do work.

```
myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(doWork));
            myThread.Start();
```

The problem is that when I leave the background worker method to go to another method and execute this :

```
browser.SelectList(Find.ById("selStartYear")).SelectByValue(startYear);
```

I get an `InvalidCastException`.

When my background worker method is finished do I need to do something with the thread? I see that I started the thread, but calling abort on it in the new method it calls just suspends the program.

**Edit:** I'm using WakiN and created new `IE` in the global scope:

```
IE browser = new IE("http://www.website.com/");
```

My worker method references this as does the failing method.

Comment: this looks like an unrelated error, hard to tell though w/o a full code sample

Comment: Some more details would be helpful. What is your background thread doing? What is the `browser` variable? Post a bit more of the code so we have an idea of execution order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to do any cleanup on a thread that has finished executing. You should actually strive never to call `Abort`, as that's a destructive method and providing a more "polite" means of signaling the thread that it should exit immediately is preferred to ending it violently with `Abort`.

Also, if your job is not particularly long-running, then you should probably be using either the new `Task` class available in `System.Threading.Tasks` or using `System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` instead of spinning up your own thread.

That being said, you aren't providing enough information to answer your `InvalidCastException` issue. What is the cast it's trying? What is the relation (if any) between the body of `doWork` and the values being used in your failing statement?

Comment: I changed my code to use a `Task`. If I wait for the task method to finish and hook up my other method to a button it works fine, but if the task method calls the other method it doesn't work (throws the error).

Comment: @Nick: You still haven't answered the question of what the failed cast actually IS.

Comment: the failed cast was the variable `startYear`. My problem was that I was calling a UI control from a non UI thread and needed to invoke failing method.

Answer (score 0):

Adam provided a complete answer on threading issue. I just another hint. Your thread (as I see in sample code) is not a background thread. Also I think all multi-thread applications needs a plan for a graceful exit (consider a system shutdown).

To find out what's the source of casting error, I suggest breaking that line of code into 3 lines, since one of the parameters is not in the right type.

Comment: I tried setting a few breakpoints on and before the line that is causing issues. The problem line is expecting a string and that's exactly what I'm giving it. I'm confused.

Comment: @Nick: You should break it into 3 lines and find-out which parameter is causing the casting exception. Then its easier to find the reason. Currently the exception might be of `startYear` or `"selStartYear"` or the return value of `Find.ById()` method (which is used by `browser.SelectList()` method as the parameter).